# Where to place php files used to connect to a database in a real web server and not WAMP

Tags: php, android, mysql, sqlite

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/) and it describes how to connect to a database using an Android app.

I need to create a folder structure similar to the one below:
[image]

My Question is where in a real server should the proposed files be placed?

I have a path of *Home Directory/My Domain/....(folders)...* so do I place that structure inside or outside My Domain folder.., and if outside how I am going to access them if I use the following?

`require_once 'OUTSIDEFOLDER/include/Config.php';`

Shouldn't I be blocked by permissions?

Answer (score 0):

> My Question is where in a real server should place the proposed files?

You must place your *file.php* in the *www* folder.

For example, if you have a WAMP server installed, you must place all your files (e.g. *file.php*, etc) in a path like *c:\{wampPathInstalled}\www\mywebsite*, where *{wampPathInstalled}* is the path where WAMP is installed on the **C** drive (or if it is another drive, use that drive letter instead).

You can access the scripts by running http://localhost/mywebsite/myfile.php in a browser.

Tell me what is your real server (IIS or other) & I can indicate where the best place is in your case.

if you use plesk, your response must be in [this link](https://www.123-reg.co.uk/support/answers/Plesk/Hosting/uploading-your-website-in-plesk-guide-4006/).

Comment: it is under plesk platform I guess Apache?

Comment: your response must be in this link https://www.123-reg.co.uk/support/answers/Plesk/Hosting/uploading-your-website-in-plesk-guide-4006/

Answer (score 0):

Well ideally for productions websites I would create a directory for every site hosted and place at a location that will require sudo privileges for modifying, reading or deleting files. Therefore the directory could be inside /var/www or you could create one inside /var/data. I would always place all the configuration information for a site in a separate config file, this file will then be included in only files that requires that information. Furthermore implement your application using MVC approach where the application is served through one common router and also provide appropriate permissions to directories based on things they are doing avoid unnecessary read, write, execute permissions everywhere to your app. Hope this helps